Window .exe enters suspended state and cant be killed
I am developing a Winforms app in VS 2022 on a Win 11 PC. I have been able to modify the C# code and build executables without any problems until today when I discovered that the executable I built immediately enters the Suspended state when I double click on it. The .exe cannot be killed by Task Manager - I get an Access denied message. I get the same message when trying to kill the .exe using wmic or taskkill from an Admin command prompt and from Process explorer. Trying to resume it from Resource Monitor also gives an Access Denied message. A restart is required to kill the process. If I run the app from within VS 2022 it runs normally with the .exe status as Running rather than Suspended.

Winforms has no mechanism to suspend an app.  You ought to find out if disabling anti-malware on that machine provides a better outcome.

The Dev machine has Malwarebytes installed with the .exe listed as a safe file to be excluded from scans. I have disabled all MalwareBytes options with no effect. The exe has been included in an installer which when run on a machine without Malwarebytes installed still enters the suspended state

Turning off Real Time protection on the machine without MalwareBytes has no effect

The problem was an attempt to gain write access to a registry entry in HKLM - the statement public static RegistryKey FileLengthKey = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\FileSystem", true); when executed after .exe startup caused a crash (as revealed by Event Viewer) by a non-Administrator process. When run from within VS 2022, the process was run as an Administrator, as VS 2022 was run as such. Perhaps because the statement was executed so early, the .exe did not remove itself after crashing  but entered the suspended but unkillable state.
